# How to create private directory for Apache and php

Tags: php, apache

I have installed Apache2 on Ubuntu 17.10.
I want to create private directory for Apache and PHP, so browsers can't get the files from the directory.
But I can access the directory from PHP files.

How I can create private directory for php files?

Comment: Don't put them in the document_root of your server

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in the root of the directory you want to deny access to browsers with the following content:

```
Deny from all
```

This will block all requests from browsers through Apache and PHP will not know the difference.

Comment: Nothing difference. :(